# Building a Structured Conversation Chatbot with Python and Langchain

Tags: python, chatbot, langchain

I'm embarking on a project to develop a hotel reservation chatbot, using Python and Langchain. I have experience in programming but am a beginner in Python. Up to now, I've used no-code platforms like BotPress and Voiceflow for chatbot projects. While these tools are simple and intuitive, I want to switch to a more code-centric solution for better customization and to avoid the costs associated with these platforms.

I aim to build a chatbot capable of managing a structured conversation flow. Here's an overview of what I'm looking to achieve:

- The chatbot first asks for the user's name.
- It then offers various services (reservation, cancellation, support).
- Based on the user's choice, it asks specific questions (for example, for a reservation, asking for the city and dates).
- The chatbot needs to be adaptable to combined responses (e.g., "I want to book in Paris from August 10th to 15th").

My challenge is to structure this type of dialogue in Python, using Langchain or others library for response generation. I'm seeking advice on:

- Managing state and context in a Python script for an interactive conversation flow.
- Strategies for guiding the user while allowing some flexibility in responses.
- Experiences, examples, or suggestions for using Langchain for this kind of project.

I'm also open to exploring other technologies if they can offer better customization and reduce costs compared to solutions like BotPress and Voiceflow.

Thanks :)

I tried using the create_conversational_retrieval_agent and ChatOpenAI functions on Langchain, but it doesn't seem to be optimized for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: You might want to post an enhanced version of your question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Make sure to get familiar with their rules first.